# Most Viewed Products in a tab

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, blocks, xml

On the site I'm currently working on, there is a tabbed area for new products and supposed to have a "most viewed" tab, but "most viewed" doesn't seem to appear - even after clearing caches - whilst new products does.

I've created a new module for it at /app/code/local/VendorX/MostViewed with the following files:

#### etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VendorX_MostViewed>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </VendorX_MostViewed>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <vendorx_mostviewed>
                <class>VendorX_MostViewed_Block_MostViewed</class>
            </vendorx_mostviewed>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### Block/MostViewed.php

```
class VendorX_MostViewed_Block_MostViewed extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getMostViewedProducts()
    {
        $storeId = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        // Date
        $date = new Zend_Date();
        $toDate = $date->setDay(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');
        $fromDate = $date->subMonth(1)->getDate()->get('Y-MM-dd');

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addPriceData()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setPageSize(6);

        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('aggregation' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/bestsellers_aggregated_monthly')),
                "e.entity_id = aggregation.product_id AND aggregation.store_id={$storeId} AND aggregation.period BETWEEN '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",
                array('SUM(aggregation.qty_ordered) AS sold_quantity')
            )
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->order(array('sold_quantity DESC', 'e.created_at'));

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

#### app/design/frontend/vendorx/website/layout/local.xml

```
...
<block type="core/template" name="featured_tabs_2" template="catalog/product/list/featured/tabbed.phtml" after="-">
                <action method="setTitle"><title><![CDATA[<span class="black">Best Selling</span> Clubs]]></title></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_new" name="new-products" as="new-products" template="catalog/product/list/featured.phtml">
                    <action method="setHeading"><heading>Just Arrived</heading></action>
                    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>86400</lifetime></action>
                    <action method="setCacheKey"><key>hp_new_prods</key></action>
                </block>
                <block type="vendorx_mostviewed/mostviewed" name="most-viewed" as="most-viewed" template="catalog/product/list/featured.phtml">
                    <action method="setHeading"><heading>Most Viewed</heading></action>
                    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>86400</lifetime></action>
                    <action method="setCacheKey"><key>hp_most_viewed</key></action>
                </block>
            </block>
...
```

I have run through xdebug and for some reason it is not going in to the mostviewed class (as defined on the block type) and when I change the block type to catalog/product_new I get some products on the front end showing (albeit the same as the new-products tab block.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your config.xml it should be

```
    <blocks>
        <vendorx_mostviewed>
            <class>VendorX_MostViewed_Block</class>
        </vendorx_mostviewed>
    </blocks>
```

instead of

```
    <blocks>
        <vendorx_mostviewed>
            <class>VendorX_MostViewed_Block_MostViewed</class>
        </vendorx_mostviewed>
    </blocks>
```

Although the element name `class` might suggest otherwise, this is not a class name, but a prefix that is used for all block aliases starting with `vendorx_mostviewed/`

Also, the block alias for `VendorX_MostViewed_Block_MostViewed` will be `vendorx_mostviewed/mostViewed` (notice the capitalization). The first character of each underscore separated word is lower cased in the alias, but inner camel case must be preserved.